# Playing mp4 file using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, video-player

I have build with the following url https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer for my jqueryMobile. but the youtube/raw file is not playing from my phone. Anyone please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: share some code that you tried out or the code that isn't working. We can't wildly guess what's going on...

Comment: recently i have download the sample file from https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi-1.0.0.zip. the standalone player is working with the native app only. how to implement the script working with jquerymobile html link <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZxrao3zou4">Barfi</a>